# How can I stop auto capitalization in a html text input field on an android/samsung phone?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, input

I am trying to get all lowercase in a html text input field on a samsung android phone.

Can anyone suggest something else to try to stop the auto capitalization for the first letter in a text field?

I have tried the following and nothing works.

- CSS

  ```
  .my_username{text-transform:lowercase;}

  input[type=text] {text-transform:lowercase;}
  ```
- JS

  ```
  my_username.setAttribute("autocapitalize","off");

  in submitonenter(my_username.value.toLowerCase();)
  ```
- HTML

  ```
  input autocapitalize="off" type="text" class="my_username" name="username" size="19" value="" maxlength="19" onkeypress="submitonenter(event,this)"
  ```

Comment: What doctype are you using?  If you aren't using html 5 (<!doctype html>), then I don't think those attributes will work.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 18):

You need to to say autocapitalize="off" in your markup

Example

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
```

[Click here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2307-Disabling-Auto-Correct-And-Auto-Capitalize-Features-On-iPhone-Inputs.htm) for more details.

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted your input field exactly above and on a samsung S2 in dolphin browser it still capitalizes the first character.

Comment: @Matt correct but he tried only autocapitalize="off" he didn't tried with this combination autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off".

Comment: @kumars You're answering question about Android while refferencing to iOS article. This answer is wrong.

Comment: `autocapitalize` is a Safari specific attribute. It has no impact on the Android platform.

Comment: Google supports `autocapitalize`, too: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize

Answer (score 16):

For android phones you have to use `autocomplete="off"`

So if you want something generic, complete @kumars' answers this way:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off"/>
```

The autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes works on the iPhone or the iPad, autocomplete is for any device running Android.

NB: Use `autocapitalize="none"` instead of `autocapitalize="off"` because "off" is deprecated for autocapitalize. See [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize).

Comment: NB: there was a bug on previous versions of chrome for android that didn't take into account the autocomplete attribute but it was fixed in 2014. see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: "This bug was about autocomplete and autocorrect." Nope, sorry

Comment: `For android phones you have to use autocomplete="off"` As of 2023, the `autocapitalize="none"` works perfectly (on Android 13, chrome/kiwi-browser) for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using React, use `autoCapitalize="none"`.